# Presentation cannot be saved in a invisible mode

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop, office-addins

I am developing a PowerPoint Add-In. When a user click on a ribbon button, I will do the following jobs:

1) Save the current presentation into another presenation

2) Open the just saved presentation (let's call this presentation as PresentationA), and modify it, and finally save it.

If I open the presentation (the PresentationA) in **an invisible mode**, I cannot save it, always get the error:

**" An attempt has been made to free an RCW that is in use.  The RCW is in use on the active thread or another thread.  Attempting to free an in-use RCW can cause corruption or data loss."**

My code is:

//- the full path of the PresentationA

string pptFile = ...

//- save the current presentation as the PresentationA

PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.SaveCopyAs(pptFile);

//- open the PresentationA in an invisible mode

PowerPoint.Presentation pres = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(pptFile, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, WithWindow: **Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse**);

//- start modifying the PresentationA

....

//- now save it, and get error

pres.Save();

How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: Do you run another threads?

Comment: no, I run on the main thread.